# Why am I getting a UnicodeDecodeError when reading a .tif image with PIL?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

So I've written a python wrapper that interfaces with an optics simulator.

The simulator generates a 2-d array of floats in a binary .dat file. Then my wrapper reads the .dat file and saves the array as a .tiff file like so:

```
file = open("image.dat")

stream = numpy.fromfile(file)

PIL.Image.fromarray(stream).save(imagepath)
```

I can open those .tiff files I've made with image viewers, BUT when I later try to OPEN that .tiff file in python, with code like this...

```
array = numpy.array(Image.open(imagepath))
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 18: invalid start byte
```

I've tried saving the .dat file as both a .tif and a .tiff file. Both versions give me this error.

I've tried opening other .tif and .tiff files (i.e. ones I haven't recently created with my code), and those open just fine, so it seems like there may be something wrong with how I'm saving the .tiff files.

I've tried to open the .tif and .tiff files in a python console, outside of the rest of my code (that automatically finds filepaths, opens the .tiff files, and then does analysis). Sometimes manually opening the .tif/.tiff file works, sometimes trying to open the SAME FILE that I could read before suddenly throws up that UnicodeDecodeError. I haven't been able to find a pattern on when I will or won't get this error.

I'm a bit mystified here, because I'm not even sure why PIL.Image.open is even trying to read something in unicode. What's going on here? Is this an error other people have gotten before in this context (specifically, opening images with a package that's designed to handle images like PIL)?

I was able to narrow the issue down to these lines of code:
Good point. I'll add the full traceback here.

So I simplified everything down and get the arrow with nothing but these lines of code:

```
 import numpy

from PIL import Image

filename = C:\\Users\\cloud-user\\Desktop\\NonPretentious\\test.tiff

array = numpy.array(Image.open(filename))
```

And got the following traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\cloud-user\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4024\904707772.py", line 1, in 
array = numpy.array(Image.open(filename))

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3133, in open
im = _open_core(fp, filename, prefix, formats)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3119, in _open_core
im = factory(fp, filename)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 116, in **init**
self._open()

File "C:\Users\cloud-user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sif_parser\plugin.py", line 13, in _open
title, size, no_images, info = _sif_open._open(self.fp)

File "C:\Users\cloud-user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sif_parser_sif_open.py", line 59, in _open
if _to_string(fp.read(36)) != _MAGIC:

File "C:\Users\cloud-user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sif_parser_sif_open.py", line 12, in _to_string
return c if not isinstance(c, bytes) else c.decode('utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 18: invalid start byte

Comment: `file = open("image.dat")` If this is a binary file, then surely you should open it in binary mode?

Comment: The full traceback message might be useful in figuring out where the problem is.

Comment: Good point. Added the traceback. I'm more mystified after looking at that more closely because the error seems to be coming from a sif_parser package which I used elsewhere, but doesn't appear anywhere in the code above and has absolutely nothing to do with opening that filename.

Comment: If you have a binary DAT file, you can share it via Google Drive. If it is just floating point pixel values, how will Numpy or PIL know its height and width? What are the height and width? Is the data greyscale or RGB?

Comment: Your TIFF file is somehow being loaded by that `sif_parser` package you installed, rather than Pillow's own TIFF code - and that package is simply buggy.  Adding a `formats=['TIFF']` parameter to the `Image.open()` call should fix this.